# How to send date like 0303

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Anybody can please help me if I want to send Date data like 0303 (03-Day and 03 the Month name) in Spring Boot Data JPA. How shall I be able to send it. I used below code for that but it's not getting inserted.Thanks!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "execution")
public class Execution implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "execution_id")
    private Integer executionGroupId;
    @Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "ExecutionDate")
    private Date executionDate;
    //Generate Setters and getters
}
```

Comment: What about the year? what should be year value in your scenario?

Comment: try adding @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "ddMM")

Comment: I am using like this  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("");
             Date date = sdf.parse(jobDetails[7]);
             execution.setExecutionDate(date); jobDetails type is String[] I am getting error like Error MessageUnparseable date: "0303" How to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Try chaning SimpleDateFormat("ddMM")

Comment: Thank you! by using SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMM") it's working fine as expected.